# Test case in spring boot(mockmvc) not supporting Resttemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

I am using Mock MVC in my test case and its working fine (with out start a full HTTP server). But if I use RestTemplate in my service controller for communicating another service its coming 'unknown host exception' while running my test case. 
My service is a spring boot application and that registered in eureka server.

my code like this

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate participantsRestTemplate;
String uRL = "http://ACCOUNT-MICRO-SERVICE/api/account/accounts.json";
restTemplate.exchange(uRL, HttpMethod.POST, body, String.class);
```

'ACCOUNT-MICRO-SERVICE' is the service name that service registered in eureka server

Comment: How are you creating the RestTemplate?

Comment: to call the rest api

Comment: not why?, how?? show it

Comment: for calling the rest api

Comment: in mi opinion you are giving to many information to be able of help you. i suppose that in your integration test eureka couldn't resolve the service name. that could be for many reasons like a bad restTemplate creation, eureka registrations fails, etc.